# Unable to use a class from a package in /lib directory

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.2

I did a simple thing: I put a `jar` file I've made myself into `/lib` directory of a Play application. However, it doesn't work:

```
def index = Action {
    val a = new com.mypackage.Class123 // error! not found Class123
    Ok(views.html.index("hello"))
  }
```

It already said `sbt`, `compile`, `gen-idea` but everything is still the same.

By the way, the file `/lib/mypackage.jar` is 38Mb for some reason.

Comment: hmm, so I guess the jar is suspiciously big. What does `jar tf lib/mypackage.jar` output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `reload` in sbt. This is needed to rescan the build file; it might also be needed to rescan the `lib` directory (I'm not sure).